# Drupal Webspeech

Tags: drupal, webspeech-api

We are using webspeech(https://www.drupal.org/project/webspeech) module for text-to-speech in one of our project. Basic functionality is working fine. But when we open this site in mobile devices (samsung, apple, sony) TTS feature is not working and no error is also being displayed.
We have tried to debug the problem but not able to do so.

Any help will be much appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the module requirements it says specifically

> Flash 9+ is required on client web browser. Modern browsers those
>   support HTML5 may also work but not guaranteed.

I see you opened an issue with the maintainer, which will probably be your best source of information, but it looks like you might be hit or (mostly) miss on mobile devices for now.

Comment: Understood. We were trying to debug this on Chrome (41.x) and used web console to mimic the mobile devices. Should It still fail there ?